# IllegalArgumentException: No handler can be found for the key 'javax.security.auth.Subject.container'

Tags: ejb, openejb, java-ee-8, jacc, tomee-8

I am basically following this tutorial:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-javaee8-security-api-4/index.html?ca=drs-

My development environment: TomEE 8.0 M1 Plume

`pom.xml`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.soteria</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.security.enterprise</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

ApplicationConfig:

```
@CustomFormAuthenticationMechanismDefinition(
        loginToContinue = @LoginToContinue(
                loginPage = "/login.xhtml",
                errorPage = "/login.xhtml?error",
                useForwardToLogin = true
        )
)

@ApplicationScoped
@Named
public class ApplicationConfig {
}
```

TestServlet:

```
@WebServlet("/test")
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Inject
    SecurityContext securityContext;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        securityContext.isCallerInRole("admin");
    }
}
```

Go to http://localhost:8080/test, I get this exception:

```
    05-Dec-2018 16:38:39.132 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-219] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [servlet.TestServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No handler can be found for the key 'javax.security.auth.Subject.container'
    at javax.security.jacc.PolicyContext.getContext(PolicyContext.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.soteria.authorization.JACC$2.run(JACC.java:175)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.glassfish.soteria.authorization.JACC.getFromContext(JACC.java:173)
    at org.glassfish.soteria.authorization.JACC.getSubject(JACC.java:73)
    at org.glassfish.soteria.authorization.JACC.isCallerInRole(JACC.java:78)
    at org.glassfish.soteria.authorization.spi.impl.ReflectionAndJaccCallerDetailsResolver.isCallerInRole(ReflectionAndJaccCallerDetailsResolver.java:82)
    at org.glassfish.soteria.SecurityContextImpl.isCallerInRole(SecurityContextImpl.java:89)
    at servlet.TestServlet.doGet(TestServlet.java:20)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.EEFilter.doFilter(EEFilter.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:607)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am from Spring and Spring Security background but new to CDI and EJB.

Could you please tell me how to configure that `handler` or am I missing something?

Thank you!

Comment: I tried with same combination ( TomEE 8 +  glassfish.soteria ) and got the same error.  I noticed that Java EE  SecurityContext is not working , But it is working with Jax rs SecurityContext. Please try with that it will work. SecurityContext method will differ example isUserInRole().

Comment: use @Context
    private SecurityContext securityContext;
Since TomEE 8 has milestone release . it does't support java EE 8 security. I hope it will be available in final 8 release. that time you can remove glassfish.soteria dependency and try with enterprise security. it will work. I am also waiting for final  TomEE 8 release. Stay with TomEE :)

Comment: @Gnana `@Context` only works in JAX-RS resources, not in the Servlet that OP is using.

Answer (score 2):

The error is caused since TomEE does not fully implement JACC on which the default authorization SPI ("ReflectionAndJaccCallerDetailsResolver") of Soteria depends.

Note that TomEE does in fact support JACC, just not fully.

There's a couple of options here (from easy to more challenging):

1. The obvious; wait for TomEE 8 final which should make this work one way or the other (using either their own EE Security implementation or otherwise)
2. Implement the SPI that Soteria uses for authorization and call TomEE/Tomcat native APIs to do the same thing that the default implementation is now using JACC for.
3. Contribute to TomEE and implement the missing bits in their JACC implementation (or contribute to Tomcat with a web only implementation). There's a JIRA for that already, see [TOMEE-1912](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOMEE-1912)

I've been planning to provide an example for 2. and make the SPI more obvious in Soteria 1.1, but unfortunately haven't got around to that yet.