# Cannot inject javax.security.enterprise.SecurityContext in basic JEE8 login application

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee-8, apache-tomee, jsf-2.3

I'be been struggling for about 20 hours and also working in the weekend as you can see and I can't make this work. I think I have exhausted all the online options

I have copied the example here
https://rieckpil.de/howto-simple-form-based-authentication-for-jsf-2-3-with-java-ee-8-security-api/
in a new Dynamic web project in Eclipse for Java Enterprise Developers. I activated  JSF 2.3 in the project facets (since I know that TomEE can use them)
I copied the classes, I set the web.xml to be the same.
My project runtime is TomEE8 (which is basically Tomcat9 with CDI and other stuff)

When I try to run the project on TomEE, I get this error:

> javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Api type
> [javax.security.enterprise.SecurityContext] is not found with the
> qualifiers  Qualifiers: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default()] for
> injection into Field Injection Point, field name :  securityContext,
> Bean Owner : [LoginBacking, WebBeansType:MANAGED, Name:loginBacking,
> API Types:[java.lang.Object,LoginBacking],
> Qualifiers:[javax.inject.Named,javax.enterprise.inject.Default,javax.enterprise.inject.Any]]

I have tried creating the beans.xml file in my WEB-INF folder
I have created another bean with this annotation:

```
@FacesConfig(
    // Activates CDI build-in beans
    version = JSF_2_3 
)
```

I have tried not using TomEE and using Tomcat 9 with weld, same problem.

I have no idea how to make this work. The thing is I need to add user login to my main application, but if this simple example won't work I don't think I can do this and I'm feeling very down.
If anyone can help me see the light, I'd be appreciative. I am also open to using the old method (ManagedBean and ManagedProperty I guess), but I'm not sure if it has the same effect.
Thanks!

Comment: As an update, I think my application has a problem with the @Inject annotation.
I implemented the database store from this example 
https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/java-ee-8-security-api/app-auth-basic-store-db/src/main/java/com/baeldung/javaee/security/DatabaseSetupServlet.java
and I am getting this error on the injected class:

I had javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Api type [javax.security.enterprise.identitystore.Pbkdf2PasswordHash] is not found with the qualifiers

Comment: Another update, I have tested https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mGrDrZ1JZi0
Using CDI with an implementation of an interface injected and it works. However it does not work with these JEE specific interfaces like SecurityContext..

Comment: Which TomEE 8 did you download? There are many

Comment: Hello, I had downloaded this version: 
TomEE plus 8.0.3

Answer (score 0):

Time for an answer.
It seems like TomEE does not provide an implementation for javaee-web-api. I had to add my own.
I have added the Soteria implementation to my lib file
https://search.maven.org/classic/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22javax.security.enterprise%22
Now all seems well (at least the app is running).
Good luck!

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53629488/illegalargumentexception-no-handler-can-be-found-for-the-key-javax-security-au

Comment: Thank you for the link, yes it seems to be related, however I had not found that one in my searches. That would have definitely helped. Ultimately I have emailed the people at Baeldung to ask for help and they told me about the implementation options. I guess if I paid more attention to the tutorial, I would have seen it. Have a good day!